# How to Move a News Post to Different Site

Tags: sharepoint-online, team-sites, microsoft-teams, sharepoint-news

Good Afternoon,
I was experimenting with the "News Post" feature in SharePoint 365 / Teams and I thought I was on the public site that everyone in our organization can see, but I was on a totally different site that only my team can see. No big deal since mistakes like this is how we learn (by coming to StackExchange to ask others who have made similar mistakes ;).

It turns out that this article would be a very useful software walk-through for my users, but it would be a bit of a pain to re-create because of the number of images it contains. Is there a way to publish a News post to multiple sites? Or can I export the News post to import it to the other site? I know there are tools such as AvePoint and ShareGate that will do this for you, but you need a paid subscription for those software tools.

Any assistance is appreciated!
Thanks,
Nick

Answer (score 0):

If you want publish news post to multiple sites, you can create a hub site.

**Please following steps:**

1.Sign in **SharePoint admin center** as SharePoint Administrators or Global Administrators, click on **Active sites** and select the specific site(siteA).

2.Then click on **Hub** >> **Register as hub site**

[image]

3.Choose another site(siteB) and click on **Hub** >> **Associate with a hub**

[image]

4.Go to the another site(siteB), click on **Edit**

5.Edit the News web part, on the **News** dialog page, Please choose "**Select sites**" option and select sites from "**Sites associated with this hub**" list

[image]

[image]

6.Publish or Republish this page.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can create MS Flow to copy the news post to your destination site. You can trigger the flow on item creation.